# Left click frequently triggers right click in ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 18.04

While clicking left click from `an external mouse **(DELL wired Mouse)**` it always auto triggers the right click. and it's very annoying to use. If anyone dealing with this same problem, gimme a hand to resolve this.

Comment: Nope, the problem occurs with the external mouse, not with the touchpad. Thanks for the comment pal. And, i'm using Dell Latitude with DELL External wired mouse

Comment: I usually use Dell external mouse in my Dell Inspiron laptop running Ubuntu 18.04. I've experienced no problem so far. Does vice versa happens? Like clicking right mouse button triggers left?

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-lefthanded.html.en

I'd recommend first making sure your updates are up to date.  The above article talks about changing your mouse keys...

If the mouse works fine on other versions and or computers, then its something with the upgraded version you are on. Save your data and use the other version still out that worked fine.  OR try installing it fresh. NOT AS AN UPGRADE from 16.  I've had good luck doing a fresh install vs the upgrade route, the upgrade route has left me with device drivers not working right, that worked fine just before the upgrade :)